# Permissions inheritance on create table partition in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, permissions, partitioning

I have partitioned table with special permissions set:

```
CREATE TABLE public.paritioned_table (
    _time int8 NULL,
    ...
) PARTITION BY RANGE (_time);
```

-- Permissions

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.paritioned_table TO someuser;
```

I have a trigger that create partitions:

```
_partition := 'paritioned_table_' || to_char(to_timestamp(_time),'YYYY_MM');

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = _partition) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %', _partition;

    select extract(epoch FROM date_trunc('month', to_timestamp(_time))) into _from;
    select extract(epoch FROM date_trunc('month', to_timestamp(_time)) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') into _to;

    execute 'CREATE TABLE ' || _partition || ' PARTITION OF paritioned_table FOR VALUES FROM (' || _from || ') TO (' || _to || ')';

END IF;
```

The problem is new created partition not inherits parent tale permissions.
So my question - what is best practice to create partitions with permissions inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a trigger that runs at every `INSERT` to check if it needs to create a partition will sap some performance. Also, would you like a partition to be created if someone enters a `_time` of -100000000000?

But to your question: Partitions are their own tables, and there are no provisions for inheriting permissions or storage parameters. You have two options:

- Add a `GRANT` statement to your trigger.
- Issue an `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGE` statement that sets default privileges for all newly created tables (perhaps limited to a schema).

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. Currently added GRANT statement after  partition create.